# How to make http call in service but get response by the controller? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I`ve got a service where I call http,the problem is that I dont understand how to use $scope.photos in the controller.How to config controller and service to do this?

```
   app.service('http',function($scope,$http){
      function getAll() {
        $http.get('/allphotos').then(function success(response) {
            $scope.photos = response.data;
        }, function error(err) {
            console.log('error is:' + err.err)
        });
    }
});

    app.controller('ctrl',function ($scope, http) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all never use `$scope` inside Service/Factory/Provider. The scope is related to controllers only, a.e. deals with bind views with controllers.

---

You have a method  `getAll()` that should return Promise and you will be able to resolve it inside your controller.

Something like:

```
app.service('httpService',function(,$http){
      this.getAll = function() {
        return $http.get('/allphotos').then(function(response) {
      //  ^ 'getAll' returns Original Promis comes from '$http'
            return response.data;
      //      ^  here we resolve 'response.data' 
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('error is:' + err.err)
        });
    }
});
```

And now in controller do:

```
app.controller('ctrl',function ($scope, httpService) {
   httpService.getAll().then(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        }, function error(err) {
            console.log('error is:' + err.err)
        });
}
```

Comment: thanks,you helped me a lot!:) Btw I changed ' function getAll()' to 'this.getAll = function()' cuz it didnt work

Comment: @rebilliony yes, should be `this.getAll = ...`